# Implementing Entity Group Transactions for Azure Table Storage REST API

Tags: c#, azure, httpwebrequest, multipart, azure-table-storage

I am writing a c# client for the Azure table storage service ([Cyan](http://cyannet.codeplex.com)).

It uses an *HttpWebRequest* to call the **REST API** of the service and already supports most of the API operations.

I am at the point of implementing [**Entity Group Transactions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894038.aspx) and I am looking for the best way to do it *without having to write each request payload myself*.

I was wondering if there is any way of having my existing *WebRequest* write their payload to, say, a *MemoryStream* so that I can send them in batch in the **request multi-part payload**.
This is the only solution I can come up with that makes best reuse of the existing implementation of the table operations.

Any idea of what's the best or elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a Azure table storage client in F# and ended up manually generating the batch request payload. I would be interested in alternative ways too.

Comment: Hi @Lucifure, do you want to share the pain? I ended up doing the same, it still needs a ton of refactoring and error handling and just implements Insert and Delete, but it's working. This is the part that builds the request http://cyannet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/12533#192211 while this is the extremely painful part that parses the multipart response http://cyannet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/12533#192216 Let me know what you think, I don't feel alone anymore:)

Comment: Hi @Maghis I would love to jump in and do this but I have other pressing needs which necessitate precedence. Keep up the great work!